# I don't know the [sudo] user password to install software

Tags: apt, software-installation, sudo

When I enter `sudo apt-get install gksu`, my [sudo] user password is requested. I don't know anything about it. Please help me in this matter.
This is shown in terminal:

```
user@user-T12Rg-H:~$ sudo apt-get install gksu
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user:
```

Comment: Use the password you created when installing Ubuntu, that's is if the owner of the system and should be in `sudo` group!

Comment: When Ubuntu was installed, you created a password. It is the same password that you login with.

Comment: it is the same as your user login password

Answer (score 2):

The `sudo` command is used to **temporarily** give members of the `sudo group` privileges similar to the one `root` users have. When setting up Ubuntu you are asked to provide a `password` to proceed with installation. That is the password needed here.

Note it won't be seen on the terminal when typing as this prevents any one around from looking over your shoulder and seeing it.

That is the password that will be asked of you whenever you want to carry out any tasks that required elevated user privileges, like in this particular case.